# validar que al menos un checkbox esta cheked

Tags: php, javascript

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Tengo una tabla con una lista de materiales y un check a un lado son parte de un formulario, lo que quiero es hacer que no se envié mi formulario hasta que todos los campos estén llenos junto con mi check , por que hasta el momento lleno el formulario pero se envía aun y cuando no e seleccionado ningún material cuando no e dado click a mi check.

para validar un checkbox necesito la propiedad name , pero el detalle y mi problema surge que en el name tengo una variable que llena mi tabla y a su vez esa variable la uso para mandarla a otra pagina

name=''

y no se como cambiar eso.

```
function valida(document)
{    
 if (document.check.value =="")
    {       
        alert("Indique el material de la cotización o pedido.");
        document.check.focus();
    return false;  }
}

<?php
$m=mysql_query("select id, material from material");
?>
<?php
if (!isset($_GET['id'])) {
?>
<table class='mat' border='1'>
<tr><td>MATERIAL</td><td>Seleccione</td></tr>
<?php
while ($m1=mysql_fetch_array($m)) {
?>
<tr><td><?php echo $m1[1];?></td><td><input type='checkbox' name='<?php echo "mat".$m1[0]?>' id='check' value=''/></td></tr>
<?php 
}
?>
</table>
```

Comment: Pues si tienes este problema al usar name, puedes dejar que tus checkbox estén seleccionados al cargar el formulario, habilitando la propiedad selected="selected".

Comment: Usas alguna librería para javascript? jQuery por ejemplo?

Comment: <script src="jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vamos por parte avanzando en la respuesta.

1- por legibilidad haría un cambio en el recorrido del resultado de tu consulta par apoder utilizar los nombres de los campos en vez de utilizar el indice del campo en la consulta. Cambiamos `mysql_fetch_array` por `mysql_fetch_object` y queda de la siguiente forma:

```
<?
    while ($mat=mysql_fetch_object($m_result)) {
?>
        <tr>
            <td><?=$mat->material?></td>
            <td><input type='checkbox' name='mat<?=$mat->id?>'/></td>
          </tr>
<?
    }
?>
```

2- Para saber si un checkbox está "checkeado" hacemos uso de un selector con jQuery, con esto sabemos cuántos checkbox han sido seleccionados por el usuario, si esto da como resultado `cero` entonces no enviamos el formulario.

```
$('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length


function valida(){    
 if ($('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length==0){       
    alert("Indique el material de la cotización o pedido.");
    return false;
 }
}
```

Si falta algo más, o no comprendí a cabalidad lo que necesitabas indícamelo para corregir y ayudarte.

Comment: <?php
$m=mysql_query("select id, material from material");
?>
<?php
if (!isset($_GET['id'])) {
?>
<table class='mat' border='1'>
<tr>
<td>MATERIAL</td><td>Seleccione</td>
</tr>
<?php
while ($mat=mysql_fetch_object($m_result)) {
    ?>
<tr>
<td><?=$mat->material?></td><td><input type='checkbox' name='mat<?=$mat->id?>'/></td>
</tr>
<?php 
}
?>
</table>

Comment: cambie el while pero ahora no me aparece la tabla con los materiales

Comment: donde ejecutas tu consulta `$m=mysql_query` deberia ser `$m_result=mysql_query`

Comment: si ya funciono perfecto asi muchas gracias :)

Comment: si la respuesta resuelve tus dudas de la pregunta por favor marca la respuesta como aceptada. Saludos!